# СSS why сanvas is not sсaling

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to scale the heights of my canvas, depending on the width, but now it is strange. And i can not delete width="1200" height="1000" cause it important for other code

```css
.responsive-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}
.responsive-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.canvas {
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="22.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="responsive-box">
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="1200" height="1000" ;></canvas>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to the element with *.class* = "`canvas`" and not to elemnto with *#id* = "`canvas`"

Comment: You should flesh out your answer with an example of the code that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the CSS error as well, but it still did not fix the issue once I changed it. I was however able to get it working.

The CSS should be:

```
.responsive-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}
```

What is this code here for? Are you trying to center the box on the page?

```
/* 
.responsive-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
} */

#canvas {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #333333;
}
```

You also had the following code:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Why are you declaring all sides? You only need 2. Are you trying to center the canvas in the middle of the page?
Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/